# Changing task to "In Progress" in TFS 2015 kanban board does not reflect in Visual Studio "My Work"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, alm

With TFS 2015, when dragging a task from "Not Started" to "In Progress" on the kanban board, the task's status is updated correctly and all is good. However, when logged into Visual Studio 2015, the task does not show under the "In Progress Work" section on the "My Work" page from Team Explorer. Instead, it still just shows under "Available Work Items".

When I do it the other way around, drag a task in the Team Explorer "My Work" page to "In Progress Work", it shows correctly on the kanban board in the web portal.

Is it supposed to work both ways? If so, any thoughts on how I can get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is expected.
When we move the work item from the **Available Work Items** section into **In Progress Work** section, this will change the state of the work item to in progress and this can be shown on the **Team Web Access**, and so when we click finish or check in, but the vice versa is not true, that’s mean if I change the work item on the **Team Web Access** from **To Do** for example to **In Progress**, this will not reflect on My Work or **In Progress Work**.

**In Progress Work** section that show what you are performing right now, so it could contain tasks, code pending change, it’s very intelligent to just show only what you can do at this moment, so if there is pending change it will show a check in command, but if there is not it will not show it,  if there is also any project editing, it will show the suppress button.

So to start work on a task you just select it and click start or just drag and drop it to the **In Progress Work** section.

Just remember if you have **10 task** to do, you only can work on one task at any point of time so the story here is you will just put one task inside **In Progress Work** section that you will work on it right now so it should have only one task at point of time and this make it very intelligent to associate the task when you try to check in your code because that’s meaning you have pending change and the working task should associate if you are not finished or should be closed if you finished.

Check: https://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/tag/in-progress-work/